# Why does the Perl debugger escape single quotes in strings?

Tags: perl

I have the following variable:

```
my $search_sql = "select COUNT(*) as COUNT
                  FROM $this->{KB_OBJECT_PORTFOLIOS} K
                  WHERE K.TARGET_ID=$target_id
                  AND K.TARGET_SERVICE_ID=$target_service_id
                  and K.PARSE_PARAM='$parse_param'
                  and K.THRESHOLD='$threshold'
                  and K.`STATUS`='WITHDRAWN';"
```

When I print this in the debugger I get:

```
select COUNT(*) ... and K.PARSE_PARAM=\'bkey=9781580536998\' and ...
```

But I expected to get:

```
select COUNT(*) ... and K.PARSE_PARAM='bkey=9781580536998' and ...
```

How can I unescape the single quotes?

Comment: Don't interpolate variables in SQL statements, use placeholders instead. [Here](http://bobby-tables.com/)'s why.

Comment: There's no way that the code `"select COUNT(*) ... and K.PARSE_PARAM='$parse_param' and"` can produce the string `select COUNT(*) ... and K.PARSE_PARAM=\'bkey=9781580536998\' and` as you claim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is that Perl does *not* randomly escape characters in your strings, it is just the debugger that adds backslashes to disambiguate strings that it displays. Whatever problem you're chasing it lies somewhere else

You should use *placeholders* in your SQL string and supply the actual parameters in the call to `$sth->execute()`

There is no need to quote a column name of any sort when it is preceded by its table name, so `k.status` is fine

It would look like this

```
my $search_sql = sprintf <<__END_SQL__, $dbh->quote_identfier($this->{KB_OBJECT_PORTFOLIOS});
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
FROM %s AS k
WHERE k.target_id         = ?,
AND   k.target_service_id = ?,
AND   k.parse_param       = ?,
AND   k.threshold         = ?,
AND   k.status            = ?
__END_SQL__

my $sth = $dbh->prepare($search_sql);

$sth->execute($target_id, $target_service_id, $parse_param, $threshold, 'WITHDRAWN');
```

Answer (score 3):

That's just the way that the Perl debugger displays strings. It always displays strings within single quotes - so any single quotes within the string need to be escaped.

But it's just a display issue. Your actual string is unchanged and should work correctly.

I suspect you're guessing at what is causing some problem you are seeing. But you're guessing incorrectly. I think you need to go back a level and explain the actual problem that you're trying to solve. Put it in a new question.

Answer (score -3):

I think I found an answer by using the

```
<<EOF;
```

notation

Comment: That's the same as using quotes, it just lets you put your string on more than one line. By default the heredoc interpolates, so it's like double quotes. Don't interpolate variables into your sql. Use placeholders like choroba said. You are opening yourself up for sql injection. Some mom will exploit it.

Comment: @simbabque: The table name has to be in the prepared statement; a placeholder won't work. I generally use `sprintf` together with `$dbh->quote_identifier`.

Comment: @Borodin scroll the code to the side. I didn't mean the table name. ;-)